# Why is System.Environment.MachineName value uppercased?

Tags: .net, windows, security, .net-4.0, principalpermission

My machine name is lowercased (i see that in Advanced system settings dialog, Computer Name tab) but `System.Environment.MachineName` reports it uppercased. Why is that? This is a real problem for me because from my tests `PrincipalPermissionAttribute` performs case sensitive comparison for role names (i map my custom roles to Windows groups and my environment is non-domain). Any advise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Dns.GetHostName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostname.aspx) instead, that should return it with the correct case (at least it does on my computer).

Comment: Thanks, worked for me! Is it possible that Dns.GetHostName() may return a name different from NETBIOS name ('cause i use it to construct local Windows group names)?

Comment: @User: Well, `GetHostName` will return the DNS hostname, but I can't remember how that relates to the netbios name.

Comment: If anyone is interested (as I was) [here's the native method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738527(v=vs.85).aspx) that is called to get the result.  Has some details about the process that may be relevant if you plan on using this.

Answer (score 8):

The source for `Environment.MachineName` for .NET 4.7.1 is here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/environment.cs,be0b5c103d248dce

It p/invokes `GetComputerName` as seen here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/microsoft/win32/win32native.cs,0c7d7f4f83d4ddd0

Here is the GetComputerName function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724295(v=vs.85).aspx, which states:

> **GetComputerName retrieves only the NetBIOS name** of the local computer.
>   To retrieve the DNS host name, DNS domain name, or the fully qualified
>   DNS name, call the GetComputerNameEx function.

The MSDN for Computer Names, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724220(VS.85).aspx, states:

> NetBIOS names consist of up to 15 bytes of OEM characters including
>   letters, digits, hyphens, and periods. Some characters are specific to
>   the character set. NetBIOS names are typically represented in the OEM
>   character set. The OEM character set depends on the locale. Some OEM
>   character sets represent certain characters as two bytes. **NetBIOS
>   names, by convention, are represented in uppercase** where the
>   translation algorithm from lowercase to uppercase is OEM character set
>   dependent.

So, NetBIOS names are upper case by convention and `System.Environment.MachineName` returns the system's NetBIOS name.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this breakdown

Answer (score 1):

According to this MSDN article, its case - insensitive
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724220(VS.85).aspx

In which scenario, it is doing case sensitive comparison ?

Comment: I've just retested it and can confirm that if i have role as "MYBOX\SupportPersonnel" PrincipalPermission throws the exception but in case of "mybox\SupportPersonnel" everything works as expected. My environment is Windows 7 x64.